# generate an output from a calculation between 2 columns in R

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a data set representing movement through a 2d environment with respect to time:

```
 time(s) start_pos fwd_dist rev_dist end_pos
 1       0.0       4.0      -3.0     2.0
 2       2.0       5.1      0.5      3.0
 3       3.0       4.7      -0.5     3.5
 4       3.5       3.6      -1.8     2.1
 5       2.1       2.6      -2.1     1.0
 6       1.0       1.5      -1.5     -0.2
```

I want to make another column which is the result of a check to see which is larger between "end_pos" and "start_pos" and subtracting the larger number from "fwd_dist". I'm trying to loop through the dataset but seem to be struggling with the syntax in R

```
 i<-0
 while (i < length(data[,1]){if (data[i,4] > data[i,1]){print (data[i,2]-data[i,4])} else {print (data[i,2]-data[i,1])}; i<-i+1}
```

I keep getting the error:

```
 Error in if (data[i, 4] > data[i, 1]) { : 
   argument is of length zero
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A data frame based approach:

```
data$difference <- data$fwd_dist - pmax(data$start_pos, data$end_pos)
```

Comment: `max` will only give the *single* largest value in the two vectors you supplied to it, it will need to be `pmax`. Unfortunately, I can't edit a single character, it needs to be at least 6... @dvanic: perhaps you can edit your answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
pmax(start_pos,end_pos)
```

will give you the *parallel maximum* (i.e., componentwise) of two vectors. So you are probably looking for

```
fwd_dist-pmax(start_pos,end_pos)
```